# Using send() on a blocking socket from multiple threads

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I have read that you are not supposed to use `send()` on a blocking socket from multiple threads, but I do not know why! And if I want to use `send()` from multiple threads, is there anything I can do to allow it?

I am using Windows.

Comment: send at the same time?  or send at different times?

Comment: @thang At the same time.

Comment: if it's a stream socket, you have a problem of having the stream make sense...

Comment: @thang You mean the buffers could get mixed together?

Comment: It's safe from the kernel's point of view, as `send()` is atomic, but it doesn't  make much sense from the receiver's point of view.

Comment: @EJP An example case where `send()` is used from multiple threads is if I want to send something in the UI thread, and I have another thread that receives data, when the other thread receives something, it must echo it back. So as you can see there are two threads that could at some point call `send()` at the same time.

Comment: @Tom You can get away with it if you're using UDP, since each call to send() will result in a separate UDP packet.  With TCP it would only work if each call to send() contained a complete message; otherwise the interleaving of messages from the two threads will confuse the parser in the remote client.  But the problem is that send() can return without having sent all the data you asked it to send--which means that you can't guarantee that each call to send() will contain a full message!  So for TCP, designate one thread to handle sending and have the other thread forward to the sender-thread.

Comment: @Tom Sure but will the receiver understand the interleaved data?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Not in blocking mode, see my comment to Harry Johnston's answer.

Comment: @EJP I assumed that `send()` send the entire buffer, I was mistaken about that, as `send()` does not guarantee that. So according to this assumption, when I send "hi" from the first thread, and "hello" from the second, the receiver will receive "hi" and "hello" (or vice versa). But now I guess I will create a function that will make sure the entire buffer is sent, and enclose its body in a critical section).

Comment: @EJP I just wrote a little test program that does blocking send()'s in a loop forever -- I was able to make send() return a value greater than zero and less that the requested-send size by sending a SIGINT signal to my test program's process (and having the process handle the signal so that the default signal handler wouldn't kill the process).  (This under MacOS/X, perhaps the guarantees are different under Windows)

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental reason is that synchronous I/O functions use the handle object (sockets are implemented as handles) to keep track of whether the I/O is complete or not.

The result is that if you try to send() to the same socket from multiple threads simultaneously, send() is liable to (a) hang or (b) exit before the I/O is actually complete, with catastrophic results.

You can use a critical section to prevent the sends from overlapping, or have a designated thread that reads data to send from a queue.

Note that this only applies if the sends are to the *same* socket.  Sending to *different* sockets simultaneously is fine.

Comment: Note - this is a general rule for synchronous I/O on Windows.  It is *possible* that the socket library is an exception, perhaps for compatibility with Posix sockets.  However, unless someone can find documentation that spells this out explicitly, I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Posix requires that `send()` be atomic and complete the write in a single call in blocking mode, and Windows is meant to be Posix-compliant. There was an extensive discussion on news:comp.protocols.tcp-ip among several implementors some years back, and that was the general conclusion.

Comment: @EJP: Windows is not Posix-compliant in general.  Do you mean just in terms of the sockets implementation?